# getting started with sproutcore on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sproutcore

i wanna check out this thing called sproutcore ,

i need to install some stuff and i don't really know how to do that, anyone can help?

i need ruby, ruby gems, and some other stuff...

where can i find some information on this stuff for windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your place, I'd start with the [SproutCore Wiki](http://wiki.sproutcore.com/), especially the [Install](http://wiki.sproutcore.com/Abbot-Setting+Up) section. If the fact that it's very non-Windows scares you, have a cup of [Install SproutCore for Dummies - Windows](http://wiki.github.com/sproutit/sproutcore/install-for-dummies-windows).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Should I take it that windows dev are not welcome by SproutCore devs?

Comment: I guess so, I'm trying to find a way to install sprout core without using their build tools and without using ruby gems, and seem to be having a hard time doing it :/

Answer (score 3):

The Install SproutCore for Dummies document is gone from that link, and doesn't seem to be in the new repository.

To install SproutCore you should first install Ruby.  That's easy enough:  go to http://www.rubyinstaller.org, download an installer.

Now you can try `gem install sproutcore`.  This results in a message that dev tools are missing - the dev tools are also available at http://www.rubyinstaller.org.

Now when I try `gem install sproutcore` it says:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit... 
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
```

GCC runs for a bit and then spews out:

```
cmain.cpp: In function 'int evma_send_file_data_to_connection(long unsigned int, const char*)':
cmain.cpp:752:6: error: cannot convert 'stat*' to '_stati64*' for argument '2' to 'int _fstati64(int, _stati64*)'
make: *** [cmain.o] Error 1
```

And that's as far as I got.

Comment: fixed using ruby 1.8.7 instead of 1.9.1

Comment: My experience is that if you are running Ruby on a Windows machine and you see the text 'Building native extensions', than it's gonna blow up on you.  There's probably a gem dependency that only certain versions will run on x86 environments.  I started using VirtualBox with Ubuntu on my PC and haven't had any problems with gems yet.  I don't want to be one of those guys that says 'get another OS', but realistically you may have to try that at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but I thought I should share this [blog post](http://unicolet.blogspot.it/2012/04/installing-sproutcore-on-windows-with.html) anyway.

It describes in a fairly detailed way how I installed ruby and then Sproutcore on my Windows 7
laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I just did it from scratch and it worked the first time out. If you want to stall Ruby go [here](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit). Follow all instructions and be sure to install Dev kit. Then go [here](http://guides.sproutcore.com/getting_started.html) to install Sproutcore. It was cake. I've installed it on Windows 7 x64.